# How to flip normals with python in blender game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine, objects, normals, faces

Is there a way to flip or change the normal vector of a face using python in the blender game engine?

Comment: While or prior to running the game?

Comment: While running the game

Comment: Could you use replace mesh?

Comment: I would post the script here, but it is very lengthy,
you have to get the mesh, and then iterate through all vertices and flip them in
engine. and Blender artists is not going anywhere :) Elysium is it's mirror. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?361318-toon-style-outline&p=2811516&viewfull=1#post2811516 http://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=359864&d=1423044848

Answer (score 4):

This is only possible via Python.

Basically you turn the order of the vertices for each single polygon (face) by exchanging [the positions](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bge.types.KX_VertexProxy.html#bge.types.KX_VertexProxy.XYZ) of the first and third vertex

flipping triangles:

[image]

flipping quads:

[image]

You might need to [set the vertex normal too](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/bge.types.KX_VertexProxy.html#bge.types.KX_VertexProxy.setNormal) to correct the shading.

### Attention:

KX_PolyProxy does not provide the right vertices when the mesh consists of a mix of quads and triangles (Blender 2.73 and earlier). I do not know when this gets fixed.